# Change div background color when bootstrap image is slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: 1]

I want to do something like this image. When page load and first image is selected then "online admission" div section background color (#034121) different from other 4 div background color (#007f3d).

And when second image is running then "admission test result " div section background color change to (#034121) this color and other 4 div background color goes to this color (#007f3d).

This is continuous process for all other image and div. Likes image is indicate that div element for those image.

I am beginner in javascript. so, am not understand how can solve this.

here the bootstrap working example link: http://www.bootply.com/NSXQJ8Xmy6

Comment: make an .active class with #034121 bg color and add the class name for current slide.

Answer (score 2):

**[Updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IaLyAJaO3a)**

Basically, you need to make use of `slid.bs.carousel` event of `bootstrap-carousel` and get the index of current `carousel slide`, find the `div element` with that index in your `#hot_news` element under `div.row` and add `active` class to it. Simultaneously, before adding, remove `active class` from all other `divs` under `div.row`.

Below is how you can do it.

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var currentIndex = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    $("#hot_news .row div.active").removeClass('active');
    $("#hot_news .row div").eq(currentIndex).addClass('active');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hot_news .row div").eq(0).addClass('active'); //add to 0 by default on page load
});
```

**CSS**

```
#hot_news .active{
     background-color: #034121;
}
```